# php - parse friendly url

Tags: php, regex, friendly-url

I have url like this

```
/cp/foo-bar/another-testing
```

how to parse it with the pattern

```
/cp/{0}-{1}/{2}
```

results will be

```
0:foo
1:bar
2:another-testing
```

I need a global solution to parse all kind of url with a pattern like that. I mean using {0}, {1} flag.

Comment: if it's going to be a global solution, how come another-testing is parsed differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('#/cp/([^/]+?)-([^/]+?)/([^/]+)#'), $url, $matches)) {
    //look into $matches[1], $matches[2] and $matches[3]
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the # character mean?

Comment: @Stone It's just a delimiter. See http://pt.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, I offer a new way: using `{$s[0]}`, `{$s[1]}`, `{$s[2]}`:

```
$your_url = '/cp/foo-bar/another-testing';
$s = explode('/', $your_url);
if(!$s[0])
     array_shift($s);
if($temp = array_pop($s))
     $s[] = $temp;
//then
$result = "/cp/{$s[0]}-{$s[1]}/{$s[2]}";
```